# Selenium check for gotoif when statement is false

Tags: automation, selenium-ide

I had written a Selenium command via IDE by implementing gotoIf
when the statement is true it jumps to the label but while the statement if false it is not going to the desired label

I have attached the command and log as well

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure the code you want to execute if "home" is found is inside your gotoIf statement. It should look like below

```
gotoIf | ${test}==true | A
click | css=a.aits-log-out
label | A
```

Remove **label | B** as your gotoIf statement isn't looking for that label because you haven't defined it.

Code to copy paste if you want that as well

```
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>${test} == true</td>
    <td>A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=a.aits-log-out</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```